# R: fig.width is ignored when using ggcorrplot within Quarto for generating an HTML document

Tags: r, quarto, ggcorrplot

R: fig.width is ignored when using ggcorrplot within Quarto for generating an HTML document.

Any ideas why?

````
---
format: html
page-layout: full
embed-resources: true
code-fold: true
execute: 
  warning: false
  message: false
---

```{r, fig.width = 20}

 # fig.width working
ggplot(airquality, aes(Temp, Ozone)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)

 # fig.width not working
airquality %>%
  cor(use = "pair") %>%
  ggcorrplot()
 ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `ggcorrplot` has a fixed height/width ratio, so you could specify the `fig-height` per below (or `fig-asp`):

````
---
format: html
page-layout: full
embed-resources: true
code-fold: true
execute: 
  warning: false
  message: false
---

```{r}
#| fig-width: 20

library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Temp, Ozone)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

```{r}
#| fig-width: 20
#| fig-height: 20

airquality |> 
  cor(use = "pair") |> 
  ggcorrplot(ggtheme = theme_classic)
```
````

Side-by-side is also an option for a smaller `ggcorrplot`:

````
::: {layout="[3,1]"}

```{r}
#| fig-width: 20

library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)

ggplot(airquality, aes(Temp, Ozone)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = FALSE)
```

```{r}
#| fig-width: 20
#| fig-height: 20

airquality |> 
  cor(use = "pair") |> 
  ggcorrplot(ggtheme = theme_classic)
```

:::
````